# Correlogram With Points Beyond -1 and +1?

Tags: python, autocorrelation, statsmodels, partial-correlation

I made a partial correlation plot of the residual of a dataset using python. I got the pacf graph below with some correlation points going to 2 and -1.5. Everyone finds this strange, does someone have any explanation for what is happening?[image: PACF of over 8000 datapoints processed as 68 yearly timesteps.]

Comment: I'm afraid there is a very simple explanation --- it is an error.  Sample correlation cannot have a magnitude larger than one.

Comment: Thank you @ReinstateMonica. I think during the residual data calculation, I took bias correction of the datapoints as well. I assume that is the most likely point of error.